# Css buttons dont work with font awesome, but works perfect with hexadecimal

Tags: html, css

i got these buttons that only works with "hexadecimal" but because im limited to icons id like to make it possible to use font awesome. but when i try to change :before the background will not go all the way to the bottom, and no mather what i change it wont work.

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz3SQ.png)

heres the buttons.css:

```
/*LOGIN BUTTON*/
.button {        
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#eeeeee', EndColorStr='#cccccc');
    border: 1px solid black;
    color:#05c7f7;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    font: bold 1em/2em Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;        
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #ddd);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#fafafa', EndColorStr='#dddddd');        
}

.button:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.button:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}    

.button:before {
    float: left;  
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(5,199,247,0.5), inset 0 0 1px 1px #05c7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(5,199,247,0.5), inset 0 0 1px 1px #05c7f7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(5,199,247,0.5), inset 0 0 1px 1px #05c7f7;      
    width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 1em 0 -1em;
    padding: 0 .2em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #096aa1, #26c3f6);
    pointer-events: none;        
}


/*REGISTER BUTTON*/
.button2 {   
    cursor: pointer;     
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1a1b1f, #212528);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#eeeeee', EndColorStr='#cccccc');
    border: 1px solid black;
    color:#05c7f7;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    font: bold 1em/2em Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #ddd);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#fafafa', EndColorStr='#dddddd');        
}

.button2:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.button2:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}    

.button2:before {
    float: left;  
    color:#fff;
    background-image: url("/images/background/stripe.png");
    border-right:1px solid black;     
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
    width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 1em 0 -1em;
    padding: 0 .2em;
    pointer-events: none;         
}
```

hexadecimal.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Hexadecimal entities for the icons */

.add:before {
    content: "\271A";
}

.edit:before {
    content: "\270E";        
}

.delete:before {
    content: "\2718";        
}

.save:before {
    content: "\2714";        
}

.email:before {
    content: "\2709";        
}

.like:before {
    content: "\2764";        
}

.next:before {
    content: "\279C";
}

.star:before {
    content: "\2605";
}

.spark:before {
    content: "\2737";
}

.play:before {
    content: "\25B6";
}

.register:before {
    content: "\f044";
}

.login:before {
    content: "\f044";
}
```

and to call the buttons:

```
<div style="padding:30px; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <a class="button" href="/" >Button</a>
    <a class="button play" href="/" >Login</a>
    <a class="button2 play" href="/" >Register</a>
    <a class="button2 play" href="/" >Signout</a>
</div><br/>

<div style="padding:30px; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <a class="button" href="/" >Button</a>
    <a class="button" href="/" ><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a>
    <a class="button2" href="/" ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Register</a>
    <a class="button2" href="/" ><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Signout</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @JF-Mechs yes ive tried this but it will only display a square. only hexadecimal's that works is those that start with \2 but ive also tried it with the class's to change the css :before to i:before but then the background picture wont get all the way to the bottom of the button

Comment: I believe that if an empty square shows, css refer to a undefined icon or that icon is not available anymore. I tried to run your code and added the [font-awesome css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css) and I don't see any empty box. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa8wyvwf/)

Comment: @JF-Mechs yes that works, but if you compare it to the working buttons you can see they are not within the squares, like you can see in class="button play" where "play" becomes a icon within the blue square

Comment: the bottoms on the top is how i want them to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put font-awesome class in the `a` tag and remove the css font in `button` class
basically font-awesome icons conflicts with the css font.

See demo .

```css
/*LOGIN BUTTON*/
.button {        
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#eeeeee', EndColorStr='#cccccc');
  border: 1px solid black;
  color:#05c7f7;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  /*font: bold 1em/2em Arial, Helvetica;*/
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;        
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #ddd);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#fafafa', EndColorStr='#dddddd');        
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}    

.button:before {
  float: left;  
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(5,199,247,0.5), inset 0 0 1px 1px #05c7f7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(5,199,247,0.5), inset 0 0 1px 1px #05c7f7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(5,199,247,0.5), inset 0 0 1px 1px #05c7f7;      
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 -1em;
  padding: 0 .2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #096aa1, #26c3f6);
  pointer-events: none;        
}


/*REGISTER BUTTON*/
.button2 {   
  cursor: pointer;     
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1a1b1f, #212528);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#eeeeee', EndColorStr='#cccccc');
  border: 1px solid black;
  color:#05c7f7;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  /*font: bold 1em/2em Arial, Helvetica;*/
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fafafa, #ddd);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#fafafa', EndColorStr='#dddddd');        
}

.button2:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.button2:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}    

.button2:before {
  float: left;  
  color:#fff;
  background-image: url("/images/background/stripe.png");
  border-right:1px solid black;     
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 -1em;
  padding: 0 .2em;
  pointer-events: none;         
}

@charset "utf-8";
/* Hexadecimal entities for the icons */

.add:before {
  content: "\271A";
}

.edit:before {
  content: "\270E";        
}

.delete:before {
  content: "\2718";        
}

.save:before {
  content: "\2714";        
}

.email:before {
  content: "\2709";        
}

.like:before {
  content: "\2764";        
}

.next:before {
  content: "\279C";
}

.star:before {
  content: "\2605";
}

.spark:before {
  content: "\2737";
}

.play:before {
  content: "\25B6";
}

.register:before {
  content: "\f044";
}

.login:before {
  content: "\f044";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="padding:30px; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <a class="button play" href="/" >Login</a>
    <a class="button2 play" href="/" >Register</a>
    <a class="button2 play" href="/" >Signout</a>
</div><br/>

<div style="padding:30px; margin:0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <a class="button fa fa-lock" href="/" ><i class=""></i> Login</a>
    <a class="button2 fa fa-pencil-square-o" href="/" ><i class=""></i> Register</a>
    <a class="button2 fa fa-sign-in" href="/" ><i class=""></i> Signout</a>
</div>
```

Comment: just modify the css for buttons to improve its UI, goodluck! :)